# Converting List<ClassName> to array object to set as JComboBoxModel

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am designing classes based on DAO Pattern.

I have 3 classes and 1 GUI Form.

```
public interface SchoolYearDao {
    List<SchoolYear> getAllSchoolYearInfo();
    List<SchoolYear> getAllSchoolYearStart();
    List<SchoolYear> getAllSchoolYearEnd();
    List<SchoolYear> getSchoolYearById(int aSchoolYearId);
    int getSchoolYearId(SchoolYear schoolyear);
    boolean addSchoolYear(SchoolYear schoolyear);

}

public class SchoolYear {
 //setters and getters
}

public class SchoolYearDaoImpl implements SchoolYearDao{
@Override
    public List<SchoolYear> getAllSchoolYearStart() {
        List<SchoolYear> listOfSchoolYearStart = new ArrayList<>();
        SchoolYear mySchoolYear = new SchoolYear();
        String SQL = "{CALL getAllSchoolYearInfo()}";

        try(Connection con = DBUtil.getConnection(DBType.MYSQL);
                CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(SQL);) {
            try(ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();){
                while(rs.next()){
                    mySchoolYear.setStart(rs.getInt("yearFrom"));
                }
                listOfSchoolYearStart.add(mySchoolYear);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(listOfSchoolYearStart);
        return listOfSchoolYearStart;
    }
}
```

The problem is with the GUI.

```
public class SchoolYearGUI extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    public SchoolYearGUI() {
        initComponents();

        schoolYearStartJcbx.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(schoolyear.getAllSchoolYearInfo().toArray());
        schoolYearEndJcbx.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(schoolyear.getAllSchoolYearEnd().toArray()));
    }
}
```

I can't get the years to show correctly. I get this.

[image]

Instead of the actual integer numbers 2015,2016,2017 and so on...

I research online and found similar problems but most of them were not using a list of `class` as `List<SchoolYear>`. In this case, **"SchoolYear"** is the name of class.

I used `toArray();` and tried `Arrays.toString(array);` but can't get it right.
I thought I'd change the return type to `DefaultComboBoxModel` of `getAllSchoolYearStart()` method but I realized I have to keep my `List<SchoolYear>` as **return type** in case I need to use the result set as model for `JTables` etc..

So, I want to just stick with `List<SchoolYear>` as **return type**. (If it's a good idea?)

What is the best way to get the actual value?

Thanks in advance.

=============== Solution ==============================

Thanks to `MadProgrammer` for the advice and to other answerers.

So I studied the `listcellrenderer` overnight and finally got the basic idea of how to use it.

```
public MainFrame() {
        initComponents();
        SchoolYearDaoImpl sy = new SchoolYearDaoImpl();
        DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(sy.getAllSchoolYearStart().toArray());
        jcmbSchoolYearStart.setModel(model);
        jcmbSchoolYearStart.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                if(value instanceof SchoolYear){
                    SchoolYear schoolyear = (SchoolYear) value;
                    setText(""+schoolyear.getStart());
                }
                return this;
            }
        } );
    }
```

I overridden the `getListCellRendererComponent` and created an `if-statement` to test if value is an instance of my class which is "SchoolYear" Then I cast whatever the raw `value` is to **SchoolYear** then used the getter of SchoolYear model, `getStart()` to get the value stored in the list.

I'm now moving the renderer to an external class file in my project.

[image]

Comment: The issue is with how you a rendering (or not) the object. By default `JComboBox` will use the `toString` method of your class to generate a textual representation.  This is probably the simplest solution, override the `toString` method and return your own result. Personally, I don't like it, as it locks you into a single way to represent the object, a (IMHO) better solution is to provide you own custom `ListCellRenderer` which can format the object appropriately.

Comment: Have a look at [How to use comboboxs, providing a custom renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the help. I'm now getting the idea of using renderers which gives more flexibility. I still have a lot to learn and need to practice using it with other GUI elements.

Comment: Glad it could help

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as @MadProgrammer said, in `new DefaultComboBoxModel(schoolyear.getAllSchoolYearInfo().toArray()`, you put in an array of `Object`s, and the constructor of a `JComboBox` will try to use the `toString()` method to convert every instance of `SchoolYear` to present it as plain text. If you don't overwrite the default `toString()` method to present it as you like, you will see what you see in the combobox you have now: the class's name with some numbers.

You can implement the `toString()` method, but it's not the best way. You can construct some utility method, along with `getSchoolYearId()` you have, to get the ID of every object in the List and fill an array with the IDs.

```
private int[] getIDAndFillAnArray(List<SchoolYear> syrs) {
    int[] ids = new int[syrs.size()];
    for (int i=0; i<syrs.size(); i++) {
        ids[i] = syrs.get(i).getSchoolYearId();
    }
    return ids;
}
```

And just use it like:

```
schoolYearStartJcbx.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(getIDAndFillAnArray(schoolyear.getAllSchoolYearInfo()));
```

That's simple enough.

Comment: Thanks, this helped as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class:

```
public class ComboItem {
private String value;
private String label;

public ComboItem(String value, String label) {
    this.value = value;
    this.label = label;
}

public String getValue() {
    return this.value;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return this.label;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return label;
}
}
```

Put this method where you connect to your DB:

```
public ComboItem[] getListOfSchoolYearStart(params..)
{
List<ComboItem> result = new ArrayList<ComboItem>();
ComboItem[] items;
.....
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                ComboItem item = new ComboItem(rs.getInt("id_school") + "", rs.getString("description"));
                result.add(item);
            }
items = result.toArray(new ComboItem[result.size()]);

        return items;
}
```

Add your JComboBox:

```
 private ComboItem[] listOfSchoolYearStart;
 private int selectedIdSchool=-1; 
   ....
    listOfSchoolYearStart= getListOfSchoolYearStart();
    JComboBox comboList = new JComboBox(listOfSchoolYearStart);

    //If you want to keep previous selection
            if (listOfSchoolYearStart.length > 0)
            {
                    boolean isFound=false;
                    for (ComboItem comb : listOfSchoolYearStart) {
                        if(Integer.parseInt(comb.getValue())==selectedIdSchool)
                        {
                            comboList.setSelectedItem(comb);
                            isFound=true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!isFound)
                    {
                        comboList.setSelectedIndex(0);
                    selectedIdSchool=Integer.parseInt(listOfSchoolYearStart[0].getValue());
                    }
            }
```

This works for me at least, I hope it helps.

Comment: For all that messing around, you might as well use a `ListCellRenderer`